# Convert a map.values() returned Collection to List

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I have tried everything I knew and whatever I found online but it just is not working. I keep getting:

**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.mycompany.myproject.dto.MyDto**

I would appreciate if somebody could please tell me what I am doing wrong in the code below:

```
List<Map<Long, MyDto>> dtoList = restTemplate.getForObject(myRestUrl + "/some-path/dtoInfo/" + ids, List.class);
Map<Long, MyDto> myMap = dtoList.get(0);
System.out.println("myMap SIZE is: " + myMap.size());
System.out.println("myMap is: " + myMap);

List<MyDto> dtos = new ArrayList<MyDto>(myMap.values());
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");
for(MyDto obj : dtos) {
    sjStoreIds.add(obj.getId());
}
```

The REST call comes back with a **List** containing a **HashMap** object with the "Key" of type **Long** and the "Value" of type **MyDto**.
Then I am printing the "Size" of the map and the map itself. Both prints the correct and expected information.

Then I am extracting the list of values from the map as below:

```
List<MyDto> dtos = new ArrayList<MyDto>(myMap.values());
```

No issues there.

However, when I am trying to go through the object in the converted list (dtos) as below:

```
for(MyDto obj : dtos) {
    sjStoreIds.add(obj.getId());
}
```

I get **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.mycompany.myproject.dto.MyDto** for **for(MyDto obj : dtos) {** part.

Spinning my brains for more than 2 hours now. :(

I am sure it's going to something very basic and I will be pissed and embarrassed once I know it but can anybody please tell me where I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Following is the REST implementation I have server-side:

```
    @Override
    public List<Map<Long, MyDto>> getInfo(String idValues) {
        List<Map<Long, MyDto>> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Long, MyDto> result = new HashMap<>();

        String[] ids = idValues.split(",");
        for(String id : ids) {
            result.put(Long.parseLong(id), testInfo.get(Long.parseLong(id)));
        }

        returnList.add(result);

        return returnList;
    }
```

The "**testInfo**" above is a map that gets built as result of SQL query.

Comment: If all you're going to do with `List<MyDto> dtos` is to iterate it in a `for` loop, there is no need to convert the `Collection` to a `List`.

Comment: @Andreas - yup, I had tried that but it did not work.

Answer (score 5):

`restTemplate.getForObject` is returning you something that isn't *actually* a `List<Map<Long, MyDto>>`.  All the code you've shown is typesafe and correct, but `getForObject` silently skips type checking in its signature, and that's biting you.  Figure out what type it *really* is.  (From what you've shown us, it's probably a `List<Map<Long, Map<Something, Something>>>`.)

Comment: The `Map<Something, Something>` is likely a `Map<String, Object>` of *field name* to *value*, for the fields of `MyDto`, because the `restTemplate` was not provided with mapping information, i.e. wasn't told about `MyDto`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Louis Wasserman, appreciated! I have edited my post by adding the method similar to what I have as my REST implementation. It doesn't look like what you are saying. Any ideas on what's happening after you look at the method.

Comment: @Andreas - I think the way I am trying to do it must have been done many times by other. I did see similar approaches upon searching. I have edited my post and added the REST implementation I have, please see if you find anything wrong in there. Thanks.

Comment: @Gauzy How the server generates the JSON has no impact whatsoever on how the client processes the JSON text. Look at the actual JSON text, verify it is what you intended it to be, then figure out how to correctly parse that on the client. --- Or XML or binary or whatever form the actual transmitted data has, though being REST, it's most likely JSON.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman, what you mentioned seems the way the data is coming back to me. That is, it's in the `List<Map<Long, Map<Something, Something>>>` format.. From the error message, is does indeed look like when I am trying to get an object (my custom object) from that ArrayList it is saying `LinkedHashMap`. I am clueless on how to make it work so changed my REST implementation to return a simple `List<MyDto>` instead of `List<Map<Long, Map<Something, Something>>>`. Thanks for your quick response and help though, very much appreciated!